# How to get attribute on property in property get or set body

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to get attribute on property in property get or set body **without `StackFrame`**?

for example

```
[SomeAttribute]
public int SomeProp
{
    get
    {
        //Get of SomeAttribute is set on this property
    }
    set
    {
        //Get of SomeAttribute is set on this property
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always use `this.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProp").Attributes["AttrName"]` - but I guess you don't want to hard code property names!

Comment: Yea @VinayC It will be better to not hard code

Comment: `SomeAttribute` is only applied to the property, and not the getter or setter (methods). Please clarify your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like this and get the property name by an expression not by string lliterals

```
public string Item(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression) 
{
    if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    }
    if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand).Member.Name;
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Usage:

```
public int SomeProp
{
  get 
  { 
     var attribs = 
           this.GetType().GetProperty(this.Item(o => o.SomeProp)).Attributes;
  }
}
```