# Access attribute inside property

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have a property which has an attribute applied to it. How can i access the attribute from inside the property getter or setter?

```
class Person {

    [ID("A","B")]
    public Address HomeAddress
    {
        get
        {

            // Get values A and B here ?

        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Really no idea how to go about this.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689361/how-to-get-attribute-on-property-in-property-get-or-set-body  see this question

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am attempting to create a simple ORM and want to lazy load a complex property. In winrt there is no reflection.emit so best idea I could come up with was creating a base entity and mapping a foreign key to a local key on the property (A and B). I wanted to try to try make it clean so I dont have to write loads of code in each complex type, instead I wanted a more generic version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Person {

    [ID("A","B")]
    public Address HomeAddress
    {
        get
        {
             System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Person);
             // use attrs[0] to get "A";
             // use attrs[1] to get "B";
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Ps.: I'm not using Visual Studio right now, just wrote directly here. Sorry if you find any minor error.

---

Give a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx).

```
System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Person);  // Reflection. 

// Displaying output. 
foreach (System.Attribute attr in attrs)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine(attr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = type.GetProperties();
foreach (var m in propertyInfo )
{                    

      foreach (Attribute a in m.GetCustomAttributes(true))
      {

      }
 }
```